# Connect New MacBook 2017 (USB-C) to Apple Cinema Display 30" (DVI)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, cinema-display

I have seen that the question has been already done, but all answers refer to 2016 MacBook Pro model, meanwhile I own a 2017.

[picciano](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/60991/picciano) found a solution (see [Connect New MacBook (USB-C) to Apple Cinema Display 30" (DVI)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243920/connect-new-macbook-usb-c-to-apple-cinema-display-30-dvi/272111#272111)) but is working with this model? Has anybody tried it and had real experience?

Comment: Hi pitone78, just letting you know that the only difference between the 2016 and 2017 models of the MacBook Pro is a processor upgrade. Everything that worked for the 2016 MBP will work the same on the 2017. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jackson1442, thanks for your answer, the problem is that the brand of https://www.amazon.com/dp/B017TZTMBG/?tag=stackoverfl08-20 advices that it was not tested on 2017 model and I wanted to know if somebody here tried it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: all usb-c items should work with both.

Comment: Not a duplicate of the MacBook question.  The MacBook Pro has thunderbolt 3 in addition to usb c. That opens up many more display options like thunderbolt docks and such.

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever that the adapters that work on the 2016 MBP won't work on the 2017 model.  The 2016 has USB 3.1 and DisplayPort support; the 2017 model adds Thunderbolt (which is PCIe).  USB and DisplayPort functionality and compatibility doesn't change from machine to machine and even if they do *upgrade* them, those standards are backward compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to pass on that today (Dec. 16, 2017) I successfully ran my 30" Cinema Display from my 2017 MacBook Pro at full 2560 resolution using a combination of these two adapters:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00A493CNY/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A493CNY)

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B073ZZ46M9/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B073ZZ46M9)

It's very important to remember to plug the USB connector from the Dual Link DVI connector into a power source. Apparently that's what powers the adapter. It wasn't working until I made that connection.

Comment: The important thing to note here is that it's a DisplayPort to DVI **active** adapter–most adapters are passive, using what's know as [DisplayPort++.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Dual-mode) *Don't be fooled by the connector having the pins for dual link: "A notable limitation of dual-mode is that it can only transmit single-link DVI (and HDMI), as the number of pins in the DisplayPort connector is insufficient for dual-link connections."

Answer (score 1):

I found one of these displays locally in good condition for only 200 bucks, so I had to solve exactly this problem.

First, specs - it's this exact model:
https://everymac.com/monitors/apple/studio_cinema/specs/apple_cinema_display_30.html

My laptop is a 13" 2017 MacBook Pro w/out touch bar, so only the 2 USB-C ports on one side.

This combination of dongles works, and provides full (2560 x 1600) resolution:

$60: Monoprice Mini DisplayPort/Thunderbolt Plus USB To Dual-Link DVI Adaptor (106904)
https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B004C4SEH6/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

plus

$20: USB Type C Adapter, AllSmartLife USB C Type to Mini DisplayPort/Mini DP Adapter Cable With Aluminium Case Support 4K resolution for Apple New Macbook, ChromeBook Pixel - Grey
https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B017TZTMBG/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I hope this helps!