# Is there a dongle (or set of dongles) that allows a USB-C MacBook Pro to be connected to an Apple Cinema Display?

Tags: usb, displayport, cinema-display

I am looking for a USB-C or Thunderbolt 3 dongle that has mini DisplayPort, at least 1 USB 2/3 port, and a USB-C power delivery port.

The idea is to have a single cable between my laptop and my mini DisplayPort Cinema display. Would the Apple Digital AV Multiport Adapter work with a HDMI to DisplayPort adapter?

Edit:
This question is different from [Connect Apple 30" Cinema Display to new MacBook USB-C](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308123/connect-apple-30-cinema-display-to-new-macbook-usb-c) for a few reasons:

- The DisplayPort Cinema display uses mini DisplayPort.
- I would like only 1 cable going to the laptop.

Comment: It's unlikely you're going to find what you're looking for because the mDP connector (old type) is obsolete.  Everything now uses a Type C.  Your only two options are to go from DP Type C to HDMI back to mDP (poor option, IMO, too many conversions) or use more than one cable.  I would just get a [cable/adapter](https://amzn.to/2LzhTW9) for the monitor and live with the two cables.  IMO, performance and reliability  has higher priority over esthetics.  That or get a dock, but that's an expensive alternative.