# Can I use two USB-C to HDMI/DVI cables to hook up to two monitors from my MacBook Pro (2017)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport, dvi

I want to add a second monitor that is connected to my MacBook Pro. Right now I am using a USB-C Apple adapter which allows me to plug the HDMI to HDMI cable from the adapter to the monitor.

I want to connect a second monitor that has a DVI port so I was wondering how I could do this. Can I buy a USB-C to DVI cable and plug the USB-C side directly to the MacBook Pro USB-C port?  If that wouldn't work, what are some other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I buy a USB-C to DVI cable and plug the USB-C side directly to the MacBook Pro USB-C port?

Yes.  This is exactly how you would do it.

I would avoid using HDMI on your first monitor and instead opt for a pure DisplayPort to DisplayPort connection (the Thunderbolt ports natively output a DP signal). But if you must, use an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271) for best results.   As for the monitor that uses the DVI port, a simple converter should do, *depending on the monitor*.  Depending on the resolution that monitor is capable of, you may need a dual link DVI adapter.  In that case, it  *must* be active.

- [Connect Apple 30" Cinema Display to new MacBook USB-C](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/308123/119271)
- [What's wrong with HDMI?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/398440/119271)