# Apple Silicon M1 Mac connecting 30" Apple Cinema Display

Tags: thunderbolt, displayport, cinema-display, apple-silicon

I am attempting to connect an Apple Silicon Mac Mini, MacBook Air, and/or MacBook Pro to a 30" Apple Cinema Display at native `2560x1600` resolution.

The same question for Intel Macs with USB-C is asked here:

> - [Connect Apple 30" Cinema Display to new MacBook USB-C](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308123/connect-apple-30-cinema-display-to-new-macbook-usb-c)
> - [Connect New MacBook (USB-C) to Apple Cinema Display 30" (Dual-Link DVI)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243920/connect-new-macbook-usb-c-to-apple-cinema-display-30-dual-link-dvi)

I'm attempting to use the same chain of adapters as listed in those answers, which I have personally tested to work on an Intel USB-C Mac:

1. M1 Mac (USB-C / Thunderbolt 3)
2. USB-C to Mini DisplayPort adapter
3. [Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter](https://www.apple.com/sg_smb_5200/shop/product/MB571Z/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter)
4. Apple Cinema Display 30" (Dual-Link DVI)

However, this combination does not seem to work on my M1 Mac Mini.

I get **no screen response** on the M1 Mac. The monitor's power light is on, and USB-passthrough of my keyboard and mouse works fine, but the screen is not recognized by the Mac.

Do Apple Silicon Macs with Thunderbolt 3 require specific adapters, different from previous Intel Thunderbolt 3 Macs?

The Mac Mini-based Apple Silicon Developer Transition Kit (DTK) [did not work](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650759) with the Apple Cinema Display; I'm hoping that limitation was removed from the shipping version.

I'd like to continue to use the 30" Apple Cinema Display + Apple Dual Link DVI Adapter. Which additional adapters are needed to use that Mini DisplayPort output with an M1 Mac?

Discussion:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252063309
- https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mac-mini-m1-apple-cinema-display-30-anyone-got-it-working.2276122/

Comment: There was another thread with some other suggestions. Does [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243920/connect-new-macbook-usb-c-to-apple-cinema-display-30-dual-link-dvi?rq=1) help?

Comment: I can't test this, but have you tried any USB-C to DVI adapters instead?  https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-USB-DVI-Adapter-1920x1200/dp/B01BJ0JCBC?th=1

Answer (score 1):

I purchased a new USB-C to Mini DisplayPort adapter.

This adapter works fine connected to an M1 Mac, Apple Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter, and 30" Apple Cinema Display.

- [https://www.amazon.com/DisplayPort-Biming-Thunderbolt-Displayport-ChromeBook/dp/B086G9YH41](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086G9YH41)

[image: Biming USB-C DisplayPort]

I was previously using the same type of connector, but a few years older and from a different brand:

- https://www.amazon.ca/DisplayPort-Hamkot-Thunderbolt-Aluminum-ChromeBook/dp/B071ZKLKB1

But that adapter does not work on my M1 Mac. It does work with Intel USB-C Macs.

I would be interested to know why the original adapter does not work. Do M1 Macs require some additional spec?

Answer (score 1):

The new USB-C to Mini DisplayPort adaptor shown should work, but make sure you connect the USB2.0 lead to the computer. You don’t need to connect the FireWire 400 to anything.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, [this adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B017TZTMBG) works for me. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be available on Amazon at the moment.

The only glitch I experience is that the Cinema Display does not wake up when my MacBook Pro wakes up. I have to unplug the adapter, plug it again, and then everything works at full resolution.